# React memo keeps rendering when props have not changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a stateless functional component which has no props and populates content from React context. For reference, my app uses NextJS and is an Isomorphic App. I'm trying to use React.memo() for the first time on this component but it keeps re-rendering on client side page change, despite the props and context not changing. I know this due to my placement of a console log.

A brief example of my component is:

```
const Footer = React.memo(() => {
  const globalSettings = useContext(GlobalSettingsContext);
  console.log('Should only see this once');

  return (
    <div>
      {globalSettings.footerTitle}
    </div>
  );
});
```

I've even tried passing the second parameter with no luck:

```
const Footer = React.memo(() => {
  ...
}, () => true);
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

EDIT:
Usage of the context provider in `_app.js` looks like this:

```
class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    ...
    return { globalSettings };
  }

  render() {    
    return (
      <Container>
        <GlobalSettingsProvider settings={this.props.globalSettings}>
          ...
        </GlobalSettingsProvider>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

The actual GlobalSettingsContext file looks like this:

```
class GlobalSettingsProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { settings } = this.props;
    this.state = { value: settings };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider value={this.state.value}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default GlobalSettingsContext;
export { GlobalSettingsConsumer, GlobalSettingsProvider };
```

Comment: It might be because of `useContext`. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: Thought this might be the case. The provider for my GlobalSettingsContext wraps everything, so I can't stop that updated/re-rendering because of it's children props. So technically that value is updating every time even though the value doesn't actually change.

Comment: Have you considered using the context in the parent component and passing the `footerTitle` directly as a prop instead of context?

Comment: Can you show how you are rendering the Provider children?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I've added the code to my question

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu I might try that

Comment: Any solution? At the moment React.memo is not working for me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is coming from `useContext`. Whenever any value changes in your context, the component will re-render regardless of whether the value you're using has changed.

The solution is to create a HOC (i.e. `withMyContext()`) like so;

```
// MyContext.jsx
// exported for when you really want to use useContext();
export const MyContext = React.createContext();

// Provides values to the consumer
export function MyContextProvider(props){
  const [state, setState] = React.useState();
  const [otherValue, setOtherValue] = React.useState();
  return <MyContext.Provider value={{state, setState, otherValue, setOtherValue}} {...props} />
}

// HOC that provides the value to the component passed.
export function withMyContext(Component){
  <MyContext.Consumer>{(value) => <Component {...value} />}</MyContext.Consumer>
}

// MyComponent.jsx
const MyComponent = ({state}) => {
  // do something with state
}

// compares stringified state to determine whether to render or not. This is
// specific to this component because we only care about when state changes, 
// not otherValue
const areEqual = ({state:prev}, {state:next}) => 
  JSON.stringify(prev) !== JSON.stringify(next)

// wraps the context and memo and will prevent unnecessary 
// re-renders when otherValue changes in MyContext.
export default React.memo(withMyContext(MyComponent), areEqual)
```

Passing context as props instead of using it within render allows us to isolate the changing values we actually care about using areEqual. There's no way to make this comparison during render within `useContext`.

I would be a huge advocate for having a selector as a second argument similar to react-redux's new hooks useSelector. This would allow us to do something like

`const state = useContext(MyContext, ({state}) => state);`

Who's return value would only change when state changes, not the entire context.

But I'm just a dreamer.

This is probably the biggest argument I have right now for using react-redux over hooks for simple apps.

Comment: This was super helpful to me. I would add that it is best to use something like `react-fast-compare` instead of `JSON.stringify` to compare the changes. I have run into instances where stringify does not catch some changes and it results in a stale component. There are probably also some performance benefits when using `react-fast-compare` or similar.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful. This was posted *nearly* a year ago and my recommendation would probably change to rewriting your context so you're providing only very specific variables per context. There's no reason `GlobalSettingsProvider` can't be a composite of `UserSettingsContext`, `ThemeSettingsContext` and so on. Then you can have specific `useUserSettings`, `useThemeSettings` and so on. This will solve the problem of useContext causing re-renders for unrelated changes.