# React, NextJS: Optimizing performance for many child components that all need to re-render/update

Tags: reactjs, performance, next.js, state, rendering

I've got a parent component (Grid), which generates a number of vertical rows. Each row horizontally generates a number of cell components. Each Cell component vertically generates four subcells. I've simplified it like so:

```
// SubCell.tsx
export default function SubCell(row, column) {
  return <div>{row},{column}</div>
}


// Cell.tsx
function Cell(row, column) {
  
  const generateCell = () => {
    const subcells = [];

    for (let i=0; i<4; i++){
      subcells.push(<SubCell row={row+i} column={column}/>)
    }
  }

  return <div>{generateCell()}</div>;
}

// Grid.tsx
export default function Grid(){
  const horizontalLabels = [...];
  const verticalLabels = [...];

  const generateHeaders = () => {
    return verticalLabels.map((label, index) => {
      <div>{label}</div>
    });
  }

  const generateRows = () => {
    return (verticalLabels.map((vLabel, columnIndex) => {
      return (horizontalLabels.map((hLabel, rowIndex) => {
        return (<Cell row={rowIndex*4} column={columnIndex}/>);
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {generateHeaders()}
      {generateRows()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The components are in separate files, but I've included them together for simplicity.

My goal is to select an area of subcells; meaning, I can click my mouse down on one subcell, move it over other subcells, and the area of cells that are in the range of the mousedown cell and the mouseover cell will be highlighted. Currently, I am accomplishing this through a shared state kept in context, and passed down through Grid to cells and subcells.

```
function SubCell(row, column){
    const {currentMouseDownCell, currentMouseOverCell, setCurrentMousedownCell, setCurrentMouseOverCell} = useContext(GridContext); 

  ... the rest
  return <div 
           onMouseDown{setCurrentMousedownCell(row,column)} 
           onMouseOver={setCurrentMouseOverCell(row,column)>
            {row},{column}
         </div>
}

export default function Grid(){
  ...// everything else

  return (
    <GridContext>
       <div>
        {generateHeaders()}
        {generateRows()}
      </div>
    </GridContext>
  )
}

// GridContext.ts
export interface GridContextType {
  currentMouseDownCell: number[];
  currentMouseOverCell: number[];
  setCurrentMouseDownCell: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>;
  setCurrentMouseOverCell: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>;
}

export const GridContext = createContext<GridContextType>(
  {} as GridContextType
);

export const GridContextProvider = (children) => {
  const [currentMouseDownCell, setCurrentMouseDownCell] = useState([-1, -1]);
  const [currentMouseOverCell, setCurrentMouseOverCell] = useState([-1, -1]);

  const GridContextValue = {
    currentMouseDownCell,
    setCurrentMouseDownCell,
    currentMouseOverCell,
    setCurrentMouseOverCell,
  }

  return (
    <GridContext.Provider value={GridContextValue}>
      {children}
    </GridContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

And then for each SubCell, I'm checking for any changes to the current mousedown and mouseover subcells. If there is a change, I check if the current subcell is in between the two. If so, then I change the background to the highlighted color. If not, I change it / keep it white.

```
function SubCell(row, column) {
  const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState("white");

  const {currentMouseDownCell, currentMouseOverCell, setCurrentMousedownCell, setCurrentMouseOverCell} = useContext(GridContext);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    if row and column are in between the mousedown and mouseover cells
      setCurrentColor("blue");
    else setCurrentColor("white");
    
  }, [currentMouseDownCell, currentMouseOverCell]);

  return <div style={{backgroundColor: currentColor}}>{row},{column}</div>
}
```

This works, but with large numbers of subcells that all re-render every time a mouseover changes, it can get somewhat choppy / slow, and I'm looking for a smooth experience. Any suggestions on speed increases?

What I've tried:

- Using , but it's the same performance and I need a more customizable layout.
- Memo, but I don't see how I can avoid the re-render since every subcell needs to check if it should be highlighted every time.
- Virtualization doesn't help, because the cells will all be visible.
- Prop drilling instead of context, but that didn't make it much faster.
- Most online resources try to prevent components from doing the computation to re-render, but in my case it seems unavoidable.

**Edit 04/17/22:**
After reading [React memo keeps rendering when props have not changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763715/react-memo-keeps-rendering-when-props-have-not-changed) and this one [I'm trying to make a grid of clickable boxes where boxes know which other boxes they're adjacent to. JS/React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038404/im-trying-to-make-a-grid-of-clickable-boxes-where-boxes-know-which-other-boxes) I realized that it's better to keep the data for all cells stored at the parent level, rather than modulated individually.

I've created a 2D array, and then I've passed it down as props to the cell, and then the individual values to each subcell. This way, the parent can have the useEffect for mousedown and mouseover, do the appropriate calculations on every subcell, and then update just the relevant segments of the table. Through memoization, I can ensure that only the affected subcells are re-rendered (by checking that their old cell value is the same as the new one).